# How to handle access to inaccessible/ "invisible" properties in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, properties, getter-setter

How can we change a JavaScript class so we can create a method to handle the access to inaccessible properties?

For example, if we have a class like this one:

```
import {Map as MutableMap} from "extendable-immutable"

export class Map extends MutableMap {

    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);

        return this.asMutable()
    }
}
```

where I'm using [extendable-immutable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extendable-immutable) to extend the [ImmutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) classes. Where the focus here is not about immutability, I'm just using ImmutableJS to take advantage of its data structure features. (I'm changing the object to a mutable one in the constructor.)

With the class above we can create something like:

```
const object = new Map({"a": 1, "b": 2});
```

and access a property / key / value with:

```
object.get("a");
```

But what I'm needing is a way to access these properties like an object, for example:

```
object.a
```

The motivation for this is that some libraries, like [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) don't know how to handle this kind of access.

So instead of needing something like this:

```
const a = object.get("a");
object.set("a", 3);
```

I would like to do something like these:

```
const a = object.a;
object.a = 3;
```

I know that we could create these properties inside the class and then create getters and setters to all of them, but since I would like to use this with different kind of maps, with different keys/properties I'm searching for something more automatic.

In ruby we could use something like [method_missing](https://medium.com/podiihq/method-missing-in-ruby-af4c6edd5130), in PHP we could use some [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) like __call, __get, or __set methods.

So how could we do this in JavaScript?

Comment: You are looking for a `Proxy`. However given that you can enumerate the keys in your constructor, you could as well just dynamically create getters&setters.

Comment: I think you're looking for a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)